Is the phrase "Amazon is having best prices" grammatically correct?
Consider the phrases,



I am not having any pens.




Amazon is having the best prices.



Are the above phrases idiomatically correct?
Being from India, I encounter this phrase construction quite frequently. Is it a feature of Indian English? If yes, is there any reason why this phrase construction is more prevalent in India than other places?

It is definitely a feature of Indian English; more standard sentences would be 'I do not have any pens', and 'Amazon has the best prices'.

Some people allege it is because of verb forms in languages used in India, such as Hindi/Urdu.

There's a question on is having but it doesn't mention India, focusing on how it's incorrect elsewhere.

@StuartF That question was posted by ashish7249, that's an Indian name :).

There's a Reddit thread where people are adamant it's not due to Hindi influence, without real evidence either way; on the other hand this non-technical article blames the lack of present continuous in many Indian languages, both IE and Dravidian. Asking about the correctness of "is having" is on-topic here, but I think questions about why Indian English has certain features belong more on English Language and Usage SE.

@StuartF If you are using this phrase construction, do you even know English? It sounds so wrong to me. How does native English speaker interpret that? I am sure they are no "monolith" and different speakers will have different opinion.

To a non-Indian English speaker both expressions sound odd. We can say things like I am having a good time, where having means 'currently experiencing', but we never use the continuous tense to refer to possessions. Similarly Amazon is having a sale today (a temporary event) but not is having low prices (in general).

This form is indeed strongly associated with Indian English — so much that it is, or at least was, common in stereotypes of Indian people in England.  (To a degree that might even be considered slightly offensive in these more enlightened times.)

@gidds I think it is common because nobody is correcting its usage, and -for some reason- accepted it as Indian English.

Might be connected to the future grammar, like `I am not taking any chances'.

@gidds - as I mentioned elsewhere, in the UK, many second generation and later people of Indian heritage find such 'Inglish' sayings funny and laugh at them. I am being early for my appointment, isn't it?

@Eric I think most non-Indian English speakers interpret it exactly as intended. We may think it sounds odd, and it immediately labels the speaker as an outsider (if the Indian accent doesn't already), but it doesn't cause any confusion.

And nobody corrects it because it's considered standard in India. No one in England correct people who mistakenly call elevators "lifts". :)

@Barmar elevators are not lifts? I am confused.

They're not called lifts here.

@Barmar what is the preferred word for elevators in UK then?

It's "lift". That's my point, they use an incorrect word over there, but no one corrects it because it has become standard.

Use of the progressive aspect or 'continuous' tense, in situations where standard English uses a simple one, is a very notable feature of Indian English and one which is immediately obvious to non-Indian speakers.
Some linguists suggest that this may be due to the way verbs are formed in Hindi/Urdu:

6.2.3 Habitual and progressive aspect in Hindi/Urdu
The complex aspect system of Hindi/Urdu contains both continuous tense
forms for actions or states that are incomplete and in progress, and
habitual tense forms for actions or states which occur generally or
regularly (...).
The distribution and usage
resembles the English system, so that the forms translate relatively
easily into English. The most striking feature in verb formation in
Hindi/Urdu is the existence of compound verbs, i.e. verb forms
composed of two usually finite verbs or a verb and a noun. Examples of
the formation of these verbs (...) are
pəsənd hona "liking be" = to like
svikar kərna "acceptance do" = to accept
[A linguist] suggests that because verbs such as hear and see can be
used in the progressive form in Hindi/Urdu, a process of
transfer/interference can account for the Indian English use of
otherwise stative verbs in the progressive.

"Are you wanting a cup of coffee?"
Overuse of the progressive aspect in Indian English 

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
